# What's the meaning of the second "if" statement (caesar cipher)

Tags: c, encryption

I recently took an interest in encryption, then I came across this piece code, but I don't understand the meaning of the second "IF" statement.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char message[100], ch;
    int i, key;

    printf("Enter a message to encrypt: ");
    gets(message);
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    for (i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        ch = message[i];

        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
            ch = ch + key;

            if (ch > 'Z') {
                ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
            }
            
            message[i] = ch;
        }
    }

    printf("Encrypted message: %s", message);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It readjusts `ch` to be in the range A .. Z, notice that this code is not portable, use `if (isupper((unsigned)ch)) {` instead of `if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {`

Comment: @DavidRanieri: that fix alone will not help make this code universally portable to all encodings, so I wouldn't bother with that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer 
what fix would be best?

Comment: @EmmanuelManoloSiame: the underlying issue is that encoding become *much* more complex than ASCII is and fixing this code to work with *all* encoding turns it into a *very* different thing than what I assume is a simple exercise to learn about C and text. I'd argue it's almost entirely unrelated to this question. Basically the whole notion of "taking the character *n* steps up" turns weird if you consider the whole Unicode space.

Comment: Or to put it bluntly: Just as the caesar cipher is useful almost *exclusively* as a learning tool and historical example of encryption, treating characters as being numbers that you can increment and decrement to get meaningful values is also only useful as a learning tool and historical examples. Both the caesar cipher and this simplistic view of characters quickly becomes obsolete when trying to do "real work".

Comment: The second `if` just implements the mod 26 step.

Comment: You understand the first if but not the 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental things to understand for that code to make sense is that `char` represents *both* a character and a number at the same time.

That's because to a C program (and effectively all programs on all computers) characters are just numbers anyway.

When you say `'A'` you could equivalently use `65` or `0x41` <sup>*</sup>.

You already make use of that property by adding `key` to `ch` to "shift up" the characters (i.e. if `key` is 1 then `'A'` becomes `'B'`).

However, if you add 1 to `'Z'` then the result is no longer an upper-case character (it will be `[` in ASCII and compatible encodings).

The second if is responsible to wrap those results back down to `'A'` by first subtracting `'Z'` (which means the value is now "how many steps above Z were we) and then adding `'A' - 1` (which means that 1 step above `Z` will result in `'A`').

<sup>* Assuming this is using [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange) or a compatible encoding, which will hold true on most modern operating systems</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the calculation that is performed if the expression of the `if` statement is `true`:

```
ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
```

to

```
ch = ch - ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
```

This should already make more sense. Now the part between parentheses of course never changes value, so lets introduce a constant:

```
#define APHABET_SIZE = ('Z' - 'A' + 1)
...
ch = ch - ALPHABET_SIZE;
```

Ah, so if the value of the character is higher than Z, the last letter of the alphabet, then subtract the alphabet size.

---

This is the kind of programming that you **should not** perform yourself; it performs all the functions at once instead of breaking them down, and trades briefness for readability.

The Caesar cipher performs modular addition to shift the characters by index. You should instead have a function `int charToIndex(char)`, then perform the modular addition (or subtraction for decryption) using the `%` modulo operator and `ALPHABET_SIZE`, and then have a function `char indexToChar(int)` to convert it back.